# Conditionally Remove Variable Based on Template Type

Tags: c++, templates

Currently I am using code that looks like the below.

```
template<class T, class U = char>
struct ScoredObject {
    ScoredObject( T *object, double score, const U &data = U() ) noexcept( noexcept( U( data ) ) ) : object( object ), score( score ), data( data ) {}
    T *object;
    double score;
    U data;
    // ...
};
```

In all cases, except 1, the `data` variable is not used. It's default is `char` to just waste as little space as possible. Realistically, I'd like it to be `void`, but of course then it won't compile.

I know I can do some `std::enable_if`s on the constructor, but the issue is still with the `data` variable. Is it possible to use some sort of template "magic" to remove the `data` variable when `U` is `void`?

Basically, I want to do something like this (which I know isn't valid)

```
template<typename f = U, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_void<f>::value, bool>::type = true>
U data;
```

Comment: What about inhereting from different base classes depending on `U`?

Comment: @Evg Do you just mean having a subclass of `ScoredObject`, which has the `U`, and leave it out of `ScoredObject`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inherit `Scored_object` from different bases depending on the type of `U`. Something like this:

```
template<class T, class U>
struct Scored_object_base : Scored_object_base<T, void> {
    U data;

    using Base = Scored_object_base<T, void>;
    Scored_object_base(T* object, double score, const U& data)
        : Base(object, score), data(data) {}
};

template<class T>
struct Scored_object_base<T, void> {
    T* object;
    double score;

    Scored_object_base(T* object, double score) 
        : object(object), score(score) {}
};

template<class T, class U = void>
struct Scored_object : Scored_object_base<T, U> {
    using Base = Scored_object_base<T, U>;
    using Base::Base;
};

template<class T, class U>
bool operator==(const Scored_object<T, U>& o1, const Scored_object<T, U>& o2) {
    const auto f = (*o1.object == *o2.object && o1.score == o2.score);
    if constexpr (std::is_void_v<U>)
        return f;
    else
        return f && o1.data == o2.data;
}

int main() {
    int i;
    Scored_object<int, void> o1(&i, 1);
    Scored_object<int, char> o2(&i, 1, 'a');

    std::cout << sizeof(o1) << std::endl;   // Output: 16
    std::cout << sizeof(o2) << std::endl;   // Output: 24
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that cause a lot of slicing? `ScoredObject` contains things for `==`, `<`, etc.

Comment: @ChrisMM, it depends on how you define them. I suggest you add some relevant examples of these operators into your question.

Comment: @ChrisMM, for example, if one object doesn't have `data`, and the other one does have it, what should `operator==` do?

Comment: They'll only ever be compared against the same types. So `ScoredObject<A>` will only be compared/assigned to `ScoredObject<A>`s, never anything else.

Comment: @ChrisMM, you can define a non-member `operator==`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do the trick. The default `operator=` should be sufficient for these cases, right? :/

Comment: @ChrisMM, I guess so.

Comment: Well, it seems to be working so far, so I'll assume so. :) Thanks for the help

Comment: @ChrisMM, if you find a useful alternative solution, please let me know.

Comment: I'll probably revisit the issue for the next revision of the software in a few months. If I do find something else, I'll be sure to post it. PS: I had to splits the `operator==` into two functions to get it to work with the `noexcept` specifiers :(